# Can't open Eclipse in new workspace

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, workspace

I work upon an Android project on MacOS. Recently i had to create a copy of my project in another location. Say it was `Users/user/SVN/Applications/BarPoject/AndroidBarProject` and now it is `Users/user/Projects/AndroidBarProject`.

Now i'm trying to make Eclipse work with the project in new location. When launching Eclipse i browse to the new workspace then i click OK and then i'm presented with a popup alert which reads:

```
An error has occurred. See the log file /Users/user/Projects/AndroidBarProject/.metadata/.log
```

What i do next is i open Eclipse in the old workspace and click `File/Switch Workspace` but again i see exactly the same popup message.

I open that log file, and here are excerpts from it, which i suppose describe the problem:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/BarApp/bin/jarlist.cache' not found.
```

but i HAVE PUT jarlist.cache file into the bin directory!

further it complains again on missing jarlist.cache file and besides it:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (78).
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.dtree.ObjectNotFoundException: Tree element '/BarApp/bin/jarlist.cache' not found.
```

again i wanna emphasize that jar list.cache file is present in needed directory.
Please help me someone. I can show the whole log file content if you need

Comment: What does your .classpath file look like?